# Set SelectedIndex in WinForms ComboBox in OnLoad method

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

If I set the `SelectedIndex` of a combobox in the `OnLoad` method, the Text inside the combobox gets selected as well.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    comboBox.Items.Add("Zero");
    comboBox.Items.Add("One");
    comboBox.Items.Add("Two");

    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

[image: Text inside ComboBox is selected when Index is set inside OnLoad]

If I use the `OnShown` method for setting SelectedIndex it works as expected:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

[image: Text inside Combobox is not selected when Index is set inside OnShown]

Why does this happen and how can I avoid the behavior? Especially inside a Usercontrol, there is no OnShown method that can be used. Therefore my workaround won't work with custum UserControl.

Comment: Change the dropdownstyle to: dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to `focus` the Combo Box just change the Focus to some other control.

like

`TextBox1.Select();`

Comment: Just calling `Focus` on another TextBox in OnLoad method wont work. Text is still marked.

Comment: I have corrected my answer. You can use `TextBox1.Select();`. It should work.

Comment: In my special case (I did want the focus on another textbox) it worked but it is not always suitable. Sometimes there is no oteher Control to jump to. But I accepted your answer anyway.

Comment: By Setting the `comboBox1.TabIndex = 2;` also you can avoid this problem. But at least some control should be there to avoid this selection visibility. Like `TextBox1.TabIndex = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the focus to your Form, if what bothers you is that the text is selected.

But in general, people usually don't want the combo box options to actually be editable, which will also prevent your situation from happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the combobox to an dropdownlist by setting the DropDownStyle property to: DropDownList.

Comment: This would add heavy chrome to the UI, what the customer don't like at all. Was also my first guess.

Comment: You can always set the color yourself, to match your needs.